# Seemingly random numbers and letters to satisfy a guard

Tags: password

A party is being held at yet another local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing - his famous recipe for carbon nanotubes. He has pushed your tiny nanotube startup to the side, and sabotaging him is your only hope of achieving dominance in the carbon nanotube marketplace.

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

You hope to get in without invitation, and inject iron into the carbon so that the rich host's reputation is ruined. You watch as guests come to the door. The guard writes a combination of numbers on a board, and the guests write a string of characters:

- The guard writes "222^185" on a board. The guest writes "NOTRQNPQRST" and is admitted
- The guard writes "555^703", the guest writes "NOPNPQRST" and is admitted
- The guard writes "740^111", the guest writes "OPSTNOPQT" and is admitted
- The guard writes "962^666", to which the guest responds "OPSTNOPQRS" and is admitted
- The guard writes "111^777", the guest responds "NORQNOPS" and is killed.

You approach the door. The guard writes "37^703". What should you write to be admitted?

Hints:

> `^` is just a separator

---

> Greatest common factor, anyone?

---

> Maybe something to do with alphabets?

---

> Being in the carbon nanotube business, the host really likes chemistry. There is a large periodic table on a wall visible from the door.

Comment: Another one of these! :-ooo

Comment: password? password1? .? admin? letmein? 1234? :P

Comment: I'm not very nice, huh? Sounds like this guy earned his success and I should just try another business.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: @enderland You should go and add that comment to *all* the forty-odd "Security to the Party" questions!

Comment: Guys, if you get it wrong, you *die*. I feel like I would just go home and choose a different profession.

Comment: What's so special about rubidium?

Answer (score 4):

> With the hint about the periodic tables, (this is not an answer yet), I have identified certain trends:

### The block-code is now hidden. It is not one of the best looking spoiler-markup, but this is the only way.

### (The list still needs to be hidden! Help?)

> `# | cols. of 2        | input   | gcf`
>  `1   NO TR QN PQ RS T-   222^185   37`
>  `2   NO PN PQ RS T- --   555^703   37`
>  `3   OP ST NO PQ T- --   740^111   37`
>  `4   OP ST NO PQ RS --   962^666   74`
>  `5   NO RQ NO PS -- --   111^777   111`
>  `X   ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??   37 ^703   37`

1. All of the answers have an O, N, or P as their first two letters, and, in fact, start with either NO or OP.
2. PQRST, the consecutive letter string, appears in (1) and (2) and PQRS in (4).
3. NO is "Nobelium" or N O is "Nitrogen" + "Oxygen" ($NO_2$ is nitrous oxide, if I'm not mistaken...)
4. OP is PO backwards which is Polonium or O P is "Oxygen" + "Phosphorous" (Which is $P_4O_6$, Tetraphosphorus hexoxide)
5. TR could be short for **Tr**ansition Metal, though this is generally inconsistent (to my knowledge).
6. In all 5, it is possible to make SPQR (coincidence? I think not! We are facing the Roman takeover of `$COUNTRY`!)
7. (4) and (5) are the only even-lettered inputs.
8. We can see that each one of the five *original* inputs have a 3-digit number with the same digit (111, 222, 555, 666, and 777). Interestingly enough, it omits 333, 444, 888, and 999.

   - Furthermore, *your* input is the *only* input that (a) has no such number and (b) has a 2-digit number.
9. *LE GASP* (4) and (5) are the only problems to NOT have 37 as a GCF! We might deduce that your answer should *not* be an even-numbered amount. It may also be safe to assume $\text{len}(answer)>8$.
10. (begin editing #1) All the letters are composed of the letter-strait NOPQRST, and each solution (must) contain one of each.

    - or not. See (5) -- no T! (So we know he's definitely *not* British. Haha, $T_{ea}$!)
    - ... and (3). No R. And no pun.
11. See chart #2.
12. *WHY ONE NEEDS TO READ!* (That is, what I missed by **not** reading): (5) was killed. Huh-boy. Well, learn from others mistakes! You'd think that after witnessing someones death, you'd **not** try and attempt the feat yourself!
13. Why did (5) die?

    - Perhaps his answer was too short?
    - (5) is the only answer with two 3-like-digits. It is also one of two queries in which `x` in `x^y` is the GCF. This could simply mean `KILL` -- tough luck for you. Maybe it means naught at all.

      ---
      -

> `Chart #2`
>  `#   N's | O's | P's | Q's | R's | S's | T's | TOTAL`
>  `1    2     1     1     2     2     1     2     11`
>  `2    2     1     2     1     1     1     1      9`
>  `3    1     2     2     1     0     1     2      9`
>  `4    1     2     2     1     1     2     1     10`
>  `5    2     2     1     1     1     1     0      8`
>  `X    ?     ?     ?     ?     ?     ?     ?    ?????`
>  `$    8     8     8     6     5     6     6     47`

So what might we deduce? We could receive an insanely long string, containing 1 N, 1 O, 1 P, 3 Q, 4 R, 3 S, and 3 T (to make a grand total of 9) or 0 N, 0 O, 0 P, 2 Q, 3 R, 2 S, and 2 T (to make a total of 8).

## Meditation

### Where I 'wrap' up and theorize

- We must know that the answer is somewhat easy to come by, for the guests wrote these combination on some board.
- We may also conclude that there is some method that these guests have learned from your dreaded nano-tubist; maybe some sort of program? (Honestly, if this is the case, I'll hire a hacker to nab some of those phones and jack the program and *voila!* dreaded nano-tubist goes "bye-bye"!)
- If we only had some same test case for `x^y` for `x`! We have one for `y`, that is, `703` in (X) and (2).
- It is curious why the guard changes his methodology slightly--maybe he anticipated you, and you are doomed to fail! In that case, just use your amazing *dues ex machina* skills and whip right in there!
- From 12. on my list, I notice that 5. is killed. Perhaps there are only to be four guests, and any further 'guests' are eliminated.

Again, this are just my ideas and hypothesizing. I doubt that any of these are correct. `</muse>`

---

Any help is appreciated with the spoiler markup!

(*WIP*)

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but some ideas I've collected.

After seeing the hints, I

> broke down all the numbers into their prime factorisations

to get

> 2*3*37,5*37 gives NOTRQNPQRST.
> 3*5*37,19*37 gives NOPNPQRST.
> 2*2*5*37,3*37 gives OPSTNOPQT.
> 2*13*37,2*3*3*37 gives PSTNOPQRS.
> 3*37,3*7*37 does *not* give NORQNOPS.

The most obvious thing to notice is that

> 37 is a factor of all the numbers involved.

What can we say about the other factors? Well...

> (**2**,3;**5**) -> NOTRQNPQRST, which starts with **2** adjacent letters and ends with **5** adjacent letters.
> (**3**,**5**;19) -> NOPNPQRST, which starts with **3** adjacent letters and ends with **5** adjacent letters.
> (**2**,**2**,5;3) -> OPSTNOPQT, which starts with **2** adjacent letters and then another **2** adjacent letters.
> (**2**,13;**2**,**3**,**3**) -> OPSTNOPQRS, which starts with **2** adjacent letters followed by another **2** adjacent letters and ends with **3** adjacent letters preceded by another **3** adjacent letters (making actually 6 adjacent letters).

Am I thinking along the right lines here?

Comment: This is awesome work, but it's not quite right - I'll add another hint.

Comment: The chemical element with number 37 is RUBIDIUM.

Comment: @Martin So I [realised](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/seemingly-random-numbers-and-letters-to-satisfy-a-guard/10840?noredirect=1#comment32891_10782); can't work out the significance though.